# Apptimize - Modifiable Text / Images in app

Tags: android, analytics, apptimize

Within our application, our product designer would like the in app text and images be changeable via Apptimize.

We have a tutorial with 5 screens, each with a description and image.

Currently, for the text, I have an Array of 5 Strings, and use Apptimize's AppTimizeVar to get a value.

```
// Either use the already existing string, of the one from Apptimize.
description[i] = ApptimizeVar.createString( "tutorial_description_" + i, description[i]).value();
```

And for the images, I was going to create an Array of 5 Strings that may or may not contain URLs to an Image to replace that image.

This solution may work, but I'm wondering. Is there a better way to accomplish this goal?

Also, I wanted to get someone's opinion on if this is the right path to follow. Trying to make things changeable down the road via a third party library like Apptimize.

Thanks for your time.